# Laravel mass update enum column to different value through Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, tinker

I'm trying to do a mass-update of an enum column's value in my Laravel 9 project through tinker, my model is called `Domain` and I have an enum column called `status` with different values.

I'd like to select all entries where `status` is **expired** and set them to a different value.

I've tried running this in Tinker but it throws an error:

> PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::update() should not be called statically in /Users/ryanholton/Sites/fudge-apieval()'d code on line 1

```php
Domain::where('status', 'expired')->update(['status' => 'pending']);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what s your php version?

Comment: I'm running PHP 8.1

Comment: try this version Domain::query()->where('status', 'expired')->update(['status' => 'pending']);

Comment: Perfect, this works, if you post this as an answer I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this version

```php
Domain::query()->where('status', 'expired')->update(['status' => 'pending']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eloquent this way

```
Domain::query()->where('status', 'expired')->update(['status' => 'pending']);
```

Or You can use DB query this way

```
\DB::table('domains')->where('status', 'expired')->update(array('status' => 'pending'));
```